# Task of Modification of Sequence of Strings

Tags: c++, string, long-integer, unsigned-integer

Below is a C++ class definition for an abstract data type Sequence of strings:

```
class Sequence
{
  public:
    Sequence();    // Create an empty sequence.
    bool empty();  // Return true if the sequence is empty, otherwise false.
    int size();    // Return the number of items in the sequence.
    bool insert(int pos, const std::string& value);
       // Insert value into the sequence so that it becomes the item at
       // position pos.  The original item at position pos and those that
       // follow it end up at positions one higher than they were at before.
       // Return true if 0 <= pos <= size() and the value could be
       // inserted.  (It might not be, if the sequence has a fixed capacity,
       // e.g., because it's implemented using a fixed-size array.) Otherwise,
       // leave the sequence unchanged and return false.  Notice that
       // if pos is equal to size(), the value is inserted at the end.

    bool insert(const std::string& value);
       // Let p be the smallest integer such that value <= the item at
       // position p in the sequence; if no such item exists (i.e.,
       // value > all items in the sequence), let p be size().  Insert
       // value into the sequence so that it becomes the item at position
       // p.  The original item at position p and those that follow it end
       // up at positions one higher than before.  Return true if the value
       // was actually inserted.  Return false if the value was not inserted
       // (perhaps because the sequence has a fixed capacity and is full).

    bool erase(int pos);
       // If 0 <= pos < size(), remove the item at position pos from
       // the sequence (so that all items that followed this item end up at
       // positions one lower than they were at before), and return true.
       // Otherwise, leave the sequence unchanged and return false.

    int remove(const std::string& value);
       // Erase all items from the sequence that == value.  Return the
       // number of items removed (which will be 0 if no item == value).

    bool get(int pos, std::string& value);
       // If 0 <= pos < size(), copy into value the item at position pos
       // in the sequence and return true.  Otherwise, leave value unchanged
       // and return false.

    bool set(int pos, const std::string& value);
      // If 0 <= pos < size(), replace the item at position pos in the
      // sequence with value and return true.  Otherwise, leave the sequence
      // unchanged and return false.

    int find(const std::string& value);
      // Let p be the smallest integer such that value == the item at
      // position p in the sequence; if no such item exists, let p be -1.
      // Return p.

    void swap(Sequence& other);
      // Exchange the contents of this sequence with the other one.
};
```

Here's an example of the remove function for a Sequence of strings:

```
Sequence s;
s.insert(0, "a");
s.insert(1, "b");
s.insert(2, "c");
s.insert(3, "b");
s.insert(4, "e");
assert(s.remove("b") == 2);
assert(s.size() == 3);
string x;
assert(s.get(0, x)  &&  x == "a");
assert(s.get(1, x)  &&  x == "c");
assert(s.get(2, x)  &&  x == "e");
```

Here's an example of the swap function:

```
Sequence s1;
s1.insert(0, "paratha");
s1.insert(0, "focaccia");
Sequence s2;
s2.insert(0, "roti");
s1.swap(s2);
assert(s1.size() == 1  &&  s1.find("roti") == 0  &&  s2.size() == 2  &&
            s2.find("focaccia") == 0  &&  s2.find("paratha") == 1);
```

1. Which member functions of the Sequence class should be const member functions  (because they do not modify the Sequence)? We must change the class declaration accordingly.
2. As defined above, the Sequence class allows the client to use a sequence that contains only **std::strings**. If we are to modify the class to contain items of another type, such as only **ints** or only **doubles**, would have to make changes in many places. Modify the class definition you produced in the previous problem to use a **typedef**-defined type for all values wherever the original definition used a **std::string**. An example of a use of **typedef**:

   ```
   typedef int Number;  // define Number as a synonym for int
   int main()
   {
        Number total = 0;
        Number x;
        while (cin >> x)
        total += x;
        cout << total << endl;
   }
   ```

Modify this code to sum a sequence of longs or of doubles. Only a change in one place needs to occur: the typedef. The requirement is to use the same synonym as the **typedef**-defined name: The name **ItemType**, with exactly that spelling and case.

3. Now that an interface for a sequence class has been defined, where the item type can be easily changed, implement the class and all its member functions in such a way that the items in a sequence are contained in a data member that is an array. A sequence must be able to hold a maximum of DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS items, where

   ```
    const int DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS = 200;
   ```

The class must be tested for a Sequence of unsigned longs. The class definition and inline function definitions (if any) must be contained in a file named **Sequence.h**, and the non in-line function definitions (if any) must be contained in a file named **Sequence.cpp.**

Any private data members or private member functions may be added as needed, but nothing must be added or deleted from the public interface that was defined in the previous question, nor is it allowed to change the function signatures. The only exception to this is: It is allowed to add a public member function with the signature **void dump() const**. The intent of this function is that for testing purposes, it is capable of calling it to print information about the sequence. This function does not have to be added if not desired, but if added, it must not make any changes to the sequence. The dump function must not write to **cout**, but it's allowed to write to **cerr**.

The implementation of the Sequence class must be such that the compiler-generated destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator do the right things. A test program named **testSequence.cpp** must be written to ensure the Sequence class implementation works properly. Here is one possible (incomplete) test program:

```
#include "Sequence.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Sequence s;
    assert(s.empty());
    assert(s.find(42) == -1);
    s.insert(42);
    assert(s.size() == 1  &&  s.find(42) == 0);
    cout << "Passed all tests" << endl;
}
```

Now (only) the typedef in Sequence.h must be changed so that the Sequence will now contain **std::strings**. Except to add **#include**  if necessary, no other changes must be made to **Sequence.h**, and **Sequence.cpp**. The implementation may be verified that it builds correctly and works properly with this alternative main routine (which is not a complete test of correctness):

```
#include "Sequence.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Sequence s;
    assert(s.empty());
    assert(s.find("laobing") == -1);
    s.insert("laobing");
    assert(s.size() == 1  &&  s.find("laobing") == 0);
    cout << "Passed all tests" << endl;
}
```

The **Sequence.h** and **Sequence.cpp** code may need to be flipped between each other to fix a few times so that the only change to those files necessary to make to change a sequence's item type is to the typedef in **Sequence.h**. (When the task is complete, have them so that the item type is **unsigned** long.)

Except in the typedef statement in **Sequence.h**, the words unsigned and long must not appear in **Sequence.h** or **Sequence.cpp**. Except in the context of **#include** , the word string must not appear in **Sequence.h** or **Sequence.cpp**.

(Implementation note: The swap function is implementable without creating any additional arrays or additional Sequence)

4. Now that the class has been implemented at this point, some client code must be written that utilizes it. Implement the following class that uses a Sequence of unsigned longs:

   ```
    #include "Sequence.h"
    #include <limits>

     const unsigned long NO_SCORE = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max();
     class ScoreList
     {
       public:
         ScoreList();       // Create an empty score list.
         bool add(unsigned long score);
           // If the score is valid (a value from 0 to 100) and the score list
           // has room for it, add it to the score list and return true.
           // Otherwise, leave the score list unchanged and return false.

         bool remove(unsigned long score);
           // Remove one instance of the specified score from the score list.
           // Return true if a score was removed; otherwise false.

         int size() const;  // Return the number of scores in the list.

         unsigned long minimum() const;
           // Return the lowest score in the score list.  If the list is
           // empty, return NO_SCORE.

         unsigned long maximum() const;
           // Return the highest score in the score list.  If the list is
           // empty, return NO_SCORE.

         private:
           // Some of your code goes here.
      };
   ```

The ScoreList implementation must employ a data member of type Sequence that uses the typedef **ItemType** as a synonym for **unsigned long**. Except to change one line (the typedef in Sequence.h), no changes must be made to the **Sequence.h** and **Sequence.cpp** files produced for Question 3, so no member functions must be added to the Sequence class. Each of the member functions **add, remove, size, minimum, and maximum** must delegate as much of the work that they need to do as they can to Sequence member functions. (In other words, they must not do work themselves that they can ask Sequence member functions to do.) If the compiler-generated destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator for ScoreList don't do the right thing, they must be declared and implemented. Construct a program to test the ScoreList class. The files should be named **ScoreList.h, ScoreList.cpp, and testScoreList.cpp.**

The words **for** and **while** must not appear in **ScoreList.h** or **ScoreList.cpp**, except in the implementations of **ScoreList::minimum** and **ScoreList::maximum** if desired. The characters [ (open square bracket) and * must not appear in **StudentMultiset.h** or **StudentMultiset.cpp**, except in comments if desired. No changes have to be made for **unsigned long** to **ItemType** in **ScoreList.h** and **ScoreList.cpp** if not desired so.

5. Now that a sequence type based on arrays has been created whose size is fixed at compile time, the implementation must be changed to use a dynamically allocated array of objects. The three files produced for problem 3 must be copied, naming the new files newSequence.h, newSequence.cpp, and testnewSequence.cpp. Those files must be updated by by either adding another constructor or modifying the existing constructor so that a client can do the following:

   ```
     Sequence a(1000);   // a can hold at most 1000 items
     Sequence b(5);      // b can hold at most 5 items
     Sequence c;         // b can hold at most DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS items
     ItemType v = some value of the appropriate type;

       // No failures inserting 5 items into b
     for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
          assert(b.insert(v));

       // Failure if we try to insert a sixth item into b
     assert(!b.insert(v));

       // When two Sequences' contents are swapped, their capacities are
       // swapped as well:
     a.swap(b);
     assert(!a.insert(v)  &&  b.insert(v));
   ```

Since the compiler-generated destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator no longer do the right thing, they must be declared (as public members) and implemented. No other changes must be made to the public interface of your class. (It is allowed to make changes or additions to the private members and to the implementations of the member functions.) The implementation of the **swap** function must be changed so that the number of statement executions when swapping two sequences is the same no matter how many items are in the sequences. (This requirement would be satisfied if, for example, the **swap** function caused a loop to visit each item in the sequences, since the number of statements executed by all the iterations of the loop would depend on the number of items in the sequences.)

The character [ (open square bracket) must not appear in **newSequence.h** (but is fine in **newSequence.cpp**).

The new implementation of the Sequence class must be tested. (Even though the file is named **newSequence.h**, the name of the class defined therein must still be **Sequence**)

Verify that the ScoreList class still works properly with this new version of Sequence. The ScoreList class does not need to be changed nor its implementation in any way, other than to #include "**newSequence.h**" instead of **"Sequence.h"**. (Before ScoreList.h and ScoreList.cpp are completed, be sure that any #includes to "Sequence.h" are restored instead of "newSequence.h")

**Requirements for tasks #1-5:**

Each of the header files **Sequence.h, ScoreList.h, and newSequence.h** must have an appropriate include guard. In the files to be run and tested, the typedefs in Sequence.h and newSequence.h must define ItemType to be a synonym for unsigned long.

If a project consisting of **Sequence.h, Sequence.cpp, and testSequence.cpp** is created, it must build successfully under Visual C++.

If a project consisting of **Sequence.h, Sequence.cpp, ScoreList.h, ScoreList.cpp, and testScoreList.cpp** is created, it must build successfully under Visual C++.

If a project consisting of **newSequence.h, newSequence.cpp, and testnewSequence.cpp** is created, it must build successfully under Visual C++.

If a project is created consisting of **newSequence.h, newSequence.cpp, and testSequence.cpp**, where in testSequence.cpp only the **#include "Sequence.h"** is changed to **#include "newSequence.h"**, the project must build successfully under Visual C++. (If this is attempted, ensure that the #include back is changed to **"Sequence.h"** before running **testSequence.h**.)

No files other than those whose names begin with test may contain code that reads anything from cin or writes anything to cout, except that for question 5, the implementation of the constructor that takes an integer parameter may write a message and exit the program if the integer is negative. Any file may write to cerr (perhaps for debugging purposes); any output written to cerr will be ignored.

There must be an implementation for every member function of Sequence and ScoreList. If it not possible t get a function implemented correctly, its implementation must at least build successfully.

If **#include**  is added to **Sequence.h** that is created, change the typedef for the Sequence's item type to specify **std::string** as the item type, make no change to **Sequence.cpp**, compile **Sequence.cpp**, and link it to a file containing:

```
    #include "Sequence.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;

    void test()
    {
        Sequence s;
        assert(s.insert(0, "lavash"));
        assert(s.insert(0, "tortilla"));
        assert(s.size() == 2);
        ItemType x = "injera";
        assert(s.get(0, x) && x == "tortilla");
        assert(s.get(1, x) && x == "lavash");
    }

    int main()
    {
        test();
        cout << "Passed all tests" << endl;
    }
```

the linking must succeed. When the resulting executable is run, it must write **Passed all tests** and nothing more to **cout** and terminate normally.

If the above is successfuly achieved, then change the typedef for the Sequence's item type to specify **unsigned long** as the item type without making any other changes, recompile **Sequence.cpp**, and link it to a file containing:

```
    #include "Sequence.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;

    void test()
    {
        Sequence s;
        assert(s.insert(0, 10));
        assert(s.insert(0, 20));
        assert(s.size() == 2);
        ItemType x = 999;
        assert(s.get(0, x) && x == 20);
        assert(s.get(1, x) && x == 10);
    }

    int main()
    {
        test();
        cout << "Passed all tests" << endl;
    }
```

the linking must succeed. When the resulting executable is run, it must write **Passed all tests** and nothing more to **cout** and terminate normally.

If **#include**  is added to **newSequence.h**, change the typedef for the Sequence's item type to specify **std::string** as the item type, make no change to **newSequence.cpp**, compile **newSequence.cpp**, and link it to a file containing:

```
    #include "newSequence.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;

    void test()
    {
        Sequence s;
        assert(s.insert(0, "lavash"));
        assert(s.insert(0, "tortilla"));
        assert(s.size() == 2);
        ItemType x = "injera";
        assert(s.get(0, x) && x == "tortilla");
        assert(s.get(1, x) && x == "lavash");
    }

    int main()
    {
        test();
        cout << "Passed all tests" << endl;
    }
```

the linking must succeed. When the resulting executable is run, it must write **Passed all tests** and nothing more to **cout** and terminate normally.

If the above is successfully achieved, then change the typedef for the Sequence's item type to specify **unsigned long** as the item type without making any other changes, recompile **newSequence.cpp**, and link it to a file containing

```
    #include "newSequence.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;

    void test()
    {
        Sequence s;
        assert(s.insert(0, 10));
        assert(s.insert(0, 20));
        assert(s.size() == 2);
        ItemType x = 999;
        assert(s.get(0, x) && x == 20);
        assert(s.get(1, x) && x == 10);
    }

    int main()
    {
        test();
        cout << "Passed all tests" << endl;
    }
```

the linking must succeed. When the resulting executable is run, it must write **Passed all tests** and nothing more to **cout** and terminate normally.

Comment: Will rate highly for concise answers to questions!

Comment: What's the question?  Too long; didn't read (TL;DR).

Comment: This amount of text should be posted on the instructor's web site so that others can read it.

Comment: I can link you to the project specification site if that would be more beneficial and easier for you? Apologies for that.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your professor or TA for help.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your attempt at the assignment and what you are having issues with.

Comment: You need a much more concise question in order to get concise answers.

Comment: What part of the assignment / requirements are you having issues with?

Comment: Well, I posted the questions 1-5 above, those are the only questions that need assistance. And I've read through the entire assignment but it is still unclear to me, any help would be great!

Comment: I think you probably could have figured out the answers yourself in the time it took you to type that...